# Load application from Application List

Tags: android

I am currently working on an android project which lists all of the apps that are installed on the phone. When the user clicks on it is supposed to provide the package name so that I can later on launch the app. At the moment I am storing the package name on the next line, but I think this may confuse certain users as they don't really need to know the package name only the application name.

Therefore, is there a way that I can store the package name within the ListView (using a custom adapter with TextView and ImageView) that I can retrieve when the user selects on the app name.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is, you can use the [seTag (Object tag)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29) or [setTag(int key, Object tag)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) to store this extra info with `TextView` or any view which is extended from `View` like:

```
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textview);
tv.setTag(<package_name_string>);

tv.getTag(); // to get the value.
```

Other approach is to store that info in a separate `List` and make sure that can be accessed via Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore, is there a way that I can store the package name within the ListView (using a custom adapter with TextView and ImageView) that I can retrieve when the user selects on the app name.

The data is already in your custom adapter. As in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot), you presumably are using an `ArrayAdapter` on the `List<ResolveInfo>` you get back from `queryIntentActivities()`:

```
List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0);

Collections.sort(launchables, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm)); 

adapter=new AppAdapter(pm, launchables);
```

(where `AppAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo>`)

If so, you get the information you need to launch the app from the adapter:

```
  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v,
                                 int position, long id) {
    ResolveInfo launchable=adapter.getItem(position);
    ActivityInfo activity=launchable.activityInfo;
    ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                                         activity.name);
    Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
    i.setComponent(name);

    startActivity(i);    
  }
```